# How to configure java on Linux machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I am installing java to my Linux machine. Downloading the jre and jdk and extracting them did not help only - I assume some environmental variables are also needed. What all path variables are needed to be set? With which values? Expecting the java installs itself to `<installation-dir>`?

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: This question is not programming related. Should be moved to SF, SU, Linux or Ubuntu.

Comment: should probably be on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tim Bûthe, @tobyodavies: for my point of view coding starts from setting up the environment. Actually I got the answer and that satisfied me.

Comment: @Mikko Setälä: I'm glad you got yours answer, that's great. But setting up the environment has little to do with actually programming. Following that logic, you could ask "which operating system should I use", or "are you more productive in the morning" and so on...

Comment: @Tim Büthe and others: Thanks for opening my mind. Until now I have thought the stackoverflow as the one and unique forum for all things related to programming but looking today closer the footer of the site I explored the plurality of opportunities of StackExchange. Feelings now foolish but also amazed of the opportunities I found out.

Comment: @Tim actually you're mistaken. According to the FAQ, it is appropriate to ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and the interpreter and compiler for a programming language most certainly fall under that criteria.

Comment: The whole issue of off-topic is depending how you form your question. I did not form it well, probably. My reference [is here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94382/why-do-programming-environment-questions-always-get-closed) on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your distribution it may be easiest to install from your package manager.  On Ubuntu, for example, you can do:

```
sudo aptitude install open-jdk
```

Otherwise, usually the sun (oracle) version of java comes with a .bin file which you need to make executable and run as root in order to get java properly installed.

You shouldn't need to set any environment variables to get java to work, although some applications will require you to set JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME and/or JRE_HOME to point to the java install's bin directory.  You can see where your java install is by looking at where the symlink from

```
/etc/alternatives/java
```

points.

Comment: How to see symlink content? `more`command says this is not a text file and I can't get up with another command in mind.

Comment: You can look at a symlink with ls -atl which will give you all the details about it.  It will have an -> which points to the target of the link.  Also, readlink will do it :)

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux systems use the Gnu Java implementation by default and don't change this if you install an additional JDK. Therefore you need to explicitly make your new Java installation the default Java to be used. You can do so by running `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.

If you prefer graphical configuration, you can install the "galternatives" package, which lets you configure all those application defaults in a nice little UI.

Comment: This is the easiest and most preferable way, if more than one Java is installed by package management.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make `/usr/bin/java` point to the `java` executable in the directory where you had extracted the JRE/JDK.

If you extracted it to, say, `/opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java`, then you need to create a link like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/jdk1.6.0_23/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Prior to this, you can choose to backup an old java installation by:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java_old
```

Here is how I installed JRE: 
[Install Sun Java Runtime](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=182&t=How_To_Install_Free_PDF_Reader_In_Linux#install_sun_java_runtime_jre_ubuntu_linux).

Answer (score 1):

Get the jdk for linux. Go to the root Directory. Use the following commands to install.

./configure
make
make install

PATH .= New Path where Java is installed.

To go to the root directory for UBUNTU use command "sudo". For FEDORA use "su".